# complete event trigger before full download

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

In my app, I need to download few files form server. I used the following code:

```
function downloadFile(index:int):void
{
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadFileComplete);
    urlLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadFileProgress);
    urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onURLIOError);
    urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("some url"));
    fileNameToSave = "some name";
    trace("file name:" + fileNameToSave);
    downloading = true;
}
function onLoadFileProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var loadedPct:uint = Math.round(100 * (e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal));
}
function onURLIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("error msg");
    e.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onURLIOError);
}
function onLoadFileComplete(e:Event):void
{
    trace("File downloaded");
    var file:File;
    file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("somelocation/" + fileNameToSave);
    if(file != null)
    {
        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        fileStream.addEventListener(OutputProgressEvent.OUTPUT_PROGRESS, outputProgressHandler);
        fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSaveFile);
        fileStream.writeBytes(e.target.data);
        fileStream.close();
    }
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadFileComplete);
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadFileProgress);
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onURLIOError);
}
function outputProgressHandler(e:OutputProgressEvent):void
{
    if (e.bytesPending == 0)
    {
        trace("File is completely written");
    }
}
function onSaveFile(e:Event):void
{
    trace("Saved Complete");
    loadfiles();
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSaveFile);
}
```

It works fine. But the problem I'm having is when the internet is slow, sometime it triggers complete event even if the file is not fully downloaded. Is there anyway to prevent this? Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Is it a good practice to use progress event to check if the download is complete rather than using complete event. Like:

```
if(e.bytesLoaded >= e.bytesTotal)
{
    //downloadComplete
}
else
{
    //not complete
}
```

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't work like that. It's either COMPLETE if everything is fine, or IO_ERROR otherwise. COMPLETE should be a reliable event that is dispatched only once the data are downloaded fully and without any errors. Not that I don't believe you, but could it be something else? Like reusing loader instances, sharing one event handler between several loaders, etc?

Comment: Even if I download just one file the problems still occurs if the internet is slow. The loader is used only for this function.

Comment: The loader is inside the function. Isn't it a private variable? Sometime I do call the function multiple times to download multiple files. In that case, will the loader be reused even if the variable is inside the function?

Comment: It's not a private, it's a local variable (basically, it exists at the moment the function executes) and you create new instances of the **URLLoader**, so you do not reuse loaders but you share the event handlers between several loaders. Also, you seem not to keep the reference to the loader anywhere, so it might or might not be removed by the Garbage Collector while loading still not complete.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't think I've share event handlers between several loaders. Did you mean calling same function after creating new instances?

Comment: If you subscribe 2 instances to one event handler, then you are sharing the event handler. BTW, are you sure you should **FileStream.close()** in async mode? Async means "it will write data when it finds suitable", while you just close it right away. That might as well be the reason you are not getting data saved.

Comment: Will closing filestream after triggering close event (onSaveFile) be any different? Is there any way to find if writing process is completed?

Comment: I'm not sure FS dispatches CLOSE on writing all the data. Just test it out. Maybe it is COMPLETE, or OUTPUT_PROGRESS with **bytesPending** = 0.

Comment: Is it a good practice to use progress event to check if the download is complete rather than using complete event?

Comment: No, not really. I remember days when **bytesLoaded** and **bytesTotal** behaved obviously different for different runtimes/browsers. I don't remember details, but some configuration gave out 0 and 0 respectively on the first event thus **bytesLoaded >= bytesTotal** was passed as **true**, while **bytesLoaded / bytesTotal** produced out **Number.NaN** (or maybe **Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY**), both of which could break the workflow if you are not careful.

Comment: is there any way find the size of the file other than from progress event?

Comment: Sure: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#bytesTotal

Comment: Will close event execute on synchronous mode? if not is there save complete event on synchronous mode?

Comment: Async operation are **supposed** to rely on events. That's the way they work. Sync operations are carried out before proceeding to the next line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I can not comment because I have insufficient reputation.

I have previously had similar issue where filestream write reports as complete when in fact it has not. This occurs only on older devices and occurs randomly. My testing seemed to confirm that Flash reports file saved before the OS had actually completed. When a read then occurred it would report as file not found.

I solved it rather crudely using setTimeout and repeatedly checked if the data was complete.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What method did you use to repeatedly checking?

Comment: I simply used setTimeout to call a function that checks if the data is complete, if not it calls itself again after 50ms.

Comment: how did you get the file size? from progress event or something else?

Comment: My suggestion is a general approach rather than a specific piece of code to use. My data is JSON so I use the 'try' on JSON.parse to see if my data looks good, but you need to think of a way to validate that your data is complete.